# Why is my Points Distance result a decimal instead of miles

Tags: distance

I have a bunch of points representing residential addresses of employees and two points representing office buildings.

When I use the points distance function, the distance comes up as a decimal and not as the correct mile distance.

Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots, i.e. the tool with your inputs, as well as the map canvas of the GIS software you are using? Also, which software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your projection is probably a geographic coordinate system dealing with decimal degrees as measurement instead of a projected coordinate system using meters as a measurement unit.

Re-project your points, re-run your function, then you should get a result more favorable to you.